# Category pagination URL rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination, catalog-url-rewrite

I feel like I'm going around in circles and missing something with a particular Magento 1.9.2 setup.

Previously the site used to use URL's for category pagination URL's like :

https://www.domainname.com/category/stuff/2.html

But for some reason it has now reverted back to

https://www.domainname.com/category/stuff.html?p=2

The only reason I noticed was during an SEO Audit I noticed 404's for the previously used rewritten URL's.

How can I change them back ? I'm guessing its not a straightforward rewrite.

There is a an SEO plugin installed,  however I can't find any settings in order to accomplish it ( mirasvit seo )

Answer (score 0):

https://www.domainname.com/category/stuff.html?p=2 is default Magento1.9 behavior for paginated links.

The mirasvit extension doesn't have a setting for switching it out to the https://www.domainname.com/category/stuff/2.html

If you have those links indexed in Google or anywhere else it's either from an older version or from a different extension/custom module that you used.

As a last resort measure you can set up rewrites for your old URL's.

Comment: Yes after investigating further it does seem there was probably a different plugin installed previously. 

I think we will probably stay with ?p=2 paginated URL's.   Would you happen to have the rewrites to hand that would be required ?

Comment: How many URL'S are you dealing with?

Comment: Probably a good 1000+

Comment: Then you'll have to use some regex and htaccess - don't have that off hand

Comment: figured as much :) will get the server admin on it tomorrow and add it to the apache includes.  Thanks for the responses